# Laravel filter(remove) null and empty array values from Request

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel request I am sending data as given below..

```
{
    "user_id":13,
    "location":null,
    "about":"This Is About the user",
    "avatar":[],
    "users":[
        {
            "user_name":"John",
            "age":"30",
        },
        {
            "user_name":"Jessy",
            "age":"30",
        }
    ]
}
```

All the request keys can be null or hold a value (an array or string) so I want to filter only keys which has value.

Expected Output:

```
{
    "user_id":13,
    "about":"This Is About the user",
    "users":[
        {
            "user_name":"John",
            "age":"30",
        },
        {
            "user_name":"Jessy",
            "age":"30",
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried

```
$userRequestData = $request->only([
    'location','about','avatar','users'
]);

$Data = array_filter($userRequestData, 'strlen');
```

But it only works if the request has only string values...

How can I filter it even if it's a string or an array?

Comment: do you also want to filter the nested key-values like `user_name` key inside users?

Answer (score 2):

You can use collection to filter null values

```
collect(request()->all())->filter()
```

or

```
$result = collect(request()->all())->filter(function ($request){
    return is_string($request)&&!empty($request)||is_array($request)&&count($request);

});
```

To get array

```
$result = collect(request()->all())->filter()->toArray()
```

or for custom

```
$result = collect(request()->all())->filter(function ($request){
    return is_string($request)&&!empty($request)||is_array($request)&&count($request);
        
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass the `'strlen'` parameter to array_filter, it will filter out `falsy`values:

```
$request = [
    "user_id"=>13,
    "location"=>null,
    "about"=>"This Is About the user",
    "avatar"=>[],
    "users"=>[
        [
            "user_name"=>"John",
            "age"=>"30",
        ],
         [
            "user_name"=>"Jessy",
            "age"=>"30",
        ]
    ]
];
```

will become

```
$request = [
    "user_id"=>13,
    "about"=>"This Is About the user",
    "users"=>[
        [
            "user_name"=>"John",
            "age"=>"30",
        ],
         [
            "user_name"=>"Jessy",
            "age"=>"30",
        ]
    ]
];
```

[Documentation for array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

In your example you could do this:

```
$userRequestData = array_filter($userRequestData);
```